# How to extract innermost value with xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am not very familiar with XPath, and a google search did not return anything useful. I have the following XPath to parse a html document

```
/html/body/form[@name='qualify']/table//select[@name='ISP_ID']/option[@value='001']
```

which returns the following content:

```
<option value="001">001 Support</options>
```

What I want is to modify this XPath expression so it returns the following data:

```
001 Support
```

How do I need to modify the above XPath to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `text()` you can address the text value of a node:

```
//form[@name='qualify']/table//select[@name='ISP_ID']/option[@value='001']/text()
```

I have also simplified `/html/body/form[@name='qualify']` to `//form[@name='qualify']` because it is unlikely that you have two forms with the same name in one page.. However, it is was allowed before HTML5. That's why I hope this is OK.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of some documentation which contains the explanation of `text()`? I read some pdfs but none mentioned the `text()` function!!

Comment: I would refer to the reference documentation at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths)